# Maximum value of changing cells within given period

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I have a worksheet where Column A contains cells that have formulas and are dynamically changing. I was wondering if there is a way to capture the maximum value of each cell in Column A during the last 30 seconds and place this max in Column B. For example, A2 has a formula that changes 5 or so times during the past 30 seconds.  B2 will contain the maximum value from these changes.

Comment: What triggers the change? If it is a data link, then you cannot use any VBA change events. If it is manual input, then you can use VBA change events.

Comment: Is this a rolling 30 seconds  - ie the largest value in the past 30 secs at whatever timepoint the cell is observed?  Or is there a defined "start" and "stop" time?

Comment: @TimWilliams this is the current time-30 sec so it is continuously rolling

Comment: @TimWilliams is there any difference between the two maxinlast functions you posted below?

Comment: The first one used collections to hold the data but I replaced it with one using arrays, and the second version also fixed a couple of bugs.

Comment: Thanks man. Wouldnt the max value just be the latest value from Col A though if 30 sec goes by with no changes? Because it would technically be the max value now within the last 30 sec.

Comment: As long as there's a value in ColA then there should be a value returned from the formula.  If ColA doesn't change then neither does the formula output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2c: cache arrays of past values and times (per cell) in a static dictionary and review them each time the function is called for a specific cell.

This is a bit of a tricky question as the "last 30 sec" requirement means the function would need to be running on a regular basis, but if the inputs do not change then the function output will remain as-is.  Even making it Volatile is not a fix if nothing else on the sheet is updating.  (If your inputs are updating on a regular basis then maybe you don't need the `Application.Volatile`)

Usage (eg in B2)

```
=MaxInLast(30, A2)
```

UDF:

```vb
Function MaxInLast(numSecs As Long, rng As Range)
    
    Static dict As Object, tmp
    Dim arrTimes, arrValues, addr As String, v
    
    Application.Volatile 'otherwise will never update without 
                         '   a change to the inputs...
    
    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rng = rng.Cells(1) 'make sure we're only working with 1 cell
    addr = rng.Address
    v = rng.Value
    
    If Not dict.exists(addr) Then
        dict(addr) = Array(Array(), Array()) 'set up for this cell
    End If
    
    tmp = dict(addr)   'existing or new arrays for this cell
    arrTimes = tmp(0)  'times
    arrValues = tmp(1) 'values
    
    Debug.Print "Before clean", addr, Join(arrValues, ",")
    RemoveStaleAndAddValue arrTimes, arrValues, v, numSecs
    Debug.Print "After clean", addr, Join(arrValues, ",")
    
    If UBound(arrTimes) <> -1 Then
        MaxInLast = Application.Max(arrValues)
    Else
        MaxInLast = "" 'no data
    End If
    
    dict(addr) = Array(arrTimes, arrValues) 'cache new state
    
End Function

' Gets references to the time/value arrays
' Cleans the arrays of "stale" values and appends any new value
'   Returns new data via ByRef arguments
Sub RemoveStaleAndAddValue(ByRef arrTimes, ByRef arrValues, v, secs As Long)
    Dim tmpTimes, tmpValues, ub, n As Long, i As Long
    ub = UBound(arrTimes)
    ReDim tmpTimes(0 To ub + 1)  'new arrays for cleaned data
    ReDim tmpValues(0 To ub + 1)
    i = 0
    
    For n = 0 To ub
        If Timer - arrTimes(n) <= secs Then 'value still fresh?
            tmpTimes(i) = arrTimes(n)
            tmpValues(i) = arrValues(n)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    If Len(v) > 0 And IsNumeric(v) Then 'new value to add?
        tmpTimes(i) = Timer
        tmpValues(i) = v
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If i > 0 Then
        'resize to fit content and set ByRef arguments
        ReDim Preserve tmpTimes(0 To i - 1)
        arrTimes = tmpTimes
        ReDim Preserve tmpValues(0 To i - 1)
        arrValues = tmpValues
    Else
        'no data, just set empty arrays
        arrTimes = Array()
        arrValues = Array()
    End If
End Sub
Function MaxInLast(numSecs As Long, rng As Range)
    
    Static dict As Object, tmp
    Dim arrTimes, arrValues, i, mx, addr As String, haveValue As Boolean, v
    
    Application.Volatile 'otherwise will never update without a change to the inputs...
    
    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rng = rng.Cells(1) 'make sure we're only working with 1 cell
    addr = rng.Address
    v = rng.Value
    
    If Not dict.exists(rng.Address) Then
        dict(addr) = Array(Array(), Array()) 'set up for this cell
    End If
    
    tmp = dict(addr)   'existing or new arrays for this cell
    arrTimes = tmp(0)  'times
    arrValues = tmp(1) 'values
    
    Debug.Print "Before clean", addr, Join(arrValues, ",")
    RemoveStaleAndAddValue arrTimes, arrValues, v, numSecs
    Debug.Print "After clean", addr, Join(arrValues, ",")
    
    If UBound(arrTimes) <> -1 Then
        MaxInLast = Application.Max(arrValues)
    Else
        MaxInLast = "" 'no data
    End If
    
    dict(addr) = Array(arrTimes, arrValues) 'cache new state
    
End Function

' Gets references to the time/value arrays
' Cleans the arrays of "stale" values and appends any new value
'   Returns new data via ByRef arguments
Sub RemoveStaleAndAddValue(ByRef arrTimes, ByRef arrValues, v, secs As Long)
    Dim tmpTimes, tmpValues, ub, n As Long, i As Long
    ub = UBound(arrTimes)
    ReDim tmpTimes(0 To ub + 1)  'new arrays for cleaned data
    ReDim tmpValues(0 To ub + 1)
    i = 0
    
    For n = 0 To ub
        If Timer - arrTimes(n) <= secs Then 'value still fresh?
            tmpTimes(i) = arrTimes(n)
            tmpValues(i) = arrValues(n)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    If Len(v) > 0 And IsNumeric(v) Then 'new value to add?
        tmpTimes(i) = Timer
        tmpValues(i) = v
        i = i + 1
    End If
    If i > 0 Then
        'resize to fit content and set ByRef arguments
        ReDim Preserve tmpTimes(0 To i - 1)
        arrTimes = tmpTimes
        ReDim Preserve tmpValues(0 To i - 1)
        arrValues = tmpValues
    Else
        'no data, just set empty arrays
        arrTimes = Array()
        arrValues = Array()
    End If
End Sub
```